# How to convert a simple array to a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this first array

```
$key = array('first', 'second', 'third', ...);
```

and I would like to transform it into a $new_array that would look like this

```
array('first' => array('second' => array('third' => ...)));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: You want it recursively nested?

Comment: @rahulsm I looked for array_ fuctions in the PHP doc., foreach manipulations, asking my self, etc. And yep, recursively nested!

Comment: By the way, why are you downvoting my question? It's clear, should I write a whole paragraph to seem serious?

Comment: @FlorentBanneux My guess is that it's probably because you didn't post what you'd tried. Your question itself was quite clear IMHO. Most SO users dislike questions which seem to say ["pls send teh codez"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193581)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$keys = array('first', 'second', 'third');

$new_array = [];
$lastArray = &$new_array;
foreach ($keys as $index => $key) {
    $lastArray[$key] = [];
    $lastArray = &$lastArray[$key];
}
unset($lastArray);

print_r($new_array);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [first] => Array
        (
            [second] => Array
                (
                    [third] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Basically, it stores a reference to the last sub-array that was created, and on each iteration, adds a new sub-array with `$key => []` and then sets the reference again.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that!

Comment: @FlorentBanneux No problem :) If my answer helped you, don't forget to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)